# bash script building a find command that contains "\n"

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm having and issue building a find command in a bash script that contains \n

Here is the command I want to build

```
 find ./201911 -printf "%f\n">201911filelist.txt
```

When I test on the command line things look okay but when I put it in the script the echo treats the \n as a new line. I've tried escaping it but it doesn't work

```
# echo "find ./$dir -printf \"%f""\n"\"">${dir}filelist.txt"""
find ./201911 -printf "%f\n">201911filelist.txt
```

In my script it looks like this

```
 echo "find ./$dir -printf \"%f""\n"\"">${dir}filelist.txt""" >> create_script_$dir.sh
```

the result in the file is this:

```
find ./201909 -printf "%f
">201909filelist.txt
```

If tried this too

```
  /bin/echo -e "find ./$dir -printf \""%f\\" "n\""> ${dir}201911filelist.txt"
```

Which results in the below but I need to get rid of the space:

```
find ./201911 -printf "%f\ n"> 201911201911filelist.txt
```

I'm missing something here but I'm really close...

Comment: `echo`'s behavior is undefined by POSIX when backslashes are present. See the APPLICATION USAGE section of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, wherein the `echo` specification itself advises all new development to use `printf` instead.

Comment: ...probably what you have is not a *bash* script but a *sh* script, with a version of `sh` that follows the POSIX+XSI version of the spec and thus expands backslash-escape sequences by default.

Comment: ...anyhow, why are you using `echo` to generate code in the first place? Don't do that, *ever*. See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) -- code generation should be done by building *arrays*, not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First -- code generation in bash is for experts only, and carries serious security risks. Consider finding a different way to suit your needs.

That being said, the following behaves as-intended:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

checkShellCompat() {
  [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] && return
  echo "ERROR: Must run this script with bash, not sh" >&2
  exit 1
}

buildFindCmds() {
  # generate a correct shebang, and run the shell compatibility check
  printf '%s\n' '#!/usr/bin/env bash' "$(declare -f checkShellCompat)" checkShellCompat
  # ...then, for each directory, generate a find command with a correct redirection
  for dir; do
    printf '%q ' find "./$dir" -printf '%f\n'
    printf '>%q\n' "${dir}filelist.txt"
  done
}
buildFindCmds 201911 201912
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work.  I'm just trying to automate a very boring manual job.  Everything that is generated is throw away anyway including the directories I'm searching.

Comment: Sure; I'm just not sure I follow why you're *generating code for* the commands, vs *running* the commands.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Smart and elegant! But why `case` instead of `if [ -z "`?

Comment: @F.Hauri, heh. Habit -- I'm used to putting an actual regex for unsupported versions in there (to also filter out a `$BASH_VERSION` of `[1-3].*`, for example), but `printf %q` has been there long enough there's little point.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  It's just automation.  I have a bunch of commands that I have to run on a ton of files.  I've made the process repeatable and keying on the directory names. This find command was the last bit.  I could also just create a template script and use sed to modify it with the directory names.  That might have been easier come to think of it..

Comment: Yup.. easier... that's 4 hours I'll never get back!

Comment: I still don't see why you'd have a template script you replace names in, vs having a single *runnable* script that takes the first potentially-templatable thing as `$1`, the second as `$2`, etc. and then *actually does the job itself*, instead of generating code to do the job.

Comment: Ah Okay.  I'm never sure which YYYYMM will be available.  So I seach for what zip file I sent then build from there.  It's the way my brain works.  I was editing a for loop and pretty much got sick of that.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem here, but bash's `printf %q` format quotes/escapes the string *for consumption by bash*, so the result won't always work in other shells. For example, for strings with nonprinting characters (like an actual newline), it'll generally use ANSI C quoting (like `$'...\n...'` for a string with a newline); bash, zsh, and ksh will understand this, but dash (and probably others) won't.

Comment: Definitely true. I added the which-shell-is-in-use check for the script itself, but really should have built one for the generated code as well. That's now been edited in.

Comment: @Chris, ...so, if your script just looked for all directories with four-digit names that don't already have corresponding `filelist.txt` files, and created such files for them, would that avoid having the need to generate code at all?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to log a specific command(s), put you can use bash 'set -x', 'set +x'.

```
set -x
 find ./201911 -printf "%f\n">201911filelist.txt
 .. additional command
set +x
```

Or wrap this into a function

```
function log_and_run {
   echo "$1" >&2
   eval "$1"
}

log_and_run 'find ./201911 -printf "%f\n">201911filelist.txt'
```

As per comments, important to highlight that this log_and_run should not be used as a generic logging framework, due to potential risks associated with various expansions of the eval - see comments below.

Comment: `eval "$@"` is not at all the same thing as `"$@"`, and `echo "$@"` doesn't print anything remotely like the same thing that `set -x; "$@"` will log (before running).

Comment: Try testing with `set -- printf ' * %q\n' *`, and then comparing the output of `"$@"`, `eval "$@"`, and `printf -- '%q ' "$@" && echo`.

Comment: ...this is outright dangerous if you're dealing with filenames you don't trust; with the `eval` form, `log_and_run ls *.txt` will treat a file named `$(rm -rf ~).txt` as shell syntax, and *boom* goes your home directory. And even without malicious content, it still generates bugs, because it's concatenating all the arguments into a single string before evaluating that string as shell syntax.

Comment: I agree that log_and_run is not generic, and should not be used logging all commands. However, for the specific case that the question was posted (find + embedded new line), or similar, I do not believe that such risks exist.

Comment: Risks exist any time you don't control the full and complete text of every argument passed to `eval`. Here, `$dir` is an input, and thus not vetted at development time. "Or similar" is certainly going to contain other cases where not all values are constrained and vetted -- and again, the problems don't stop at intentionally malicious values; `eval "$@"` will also change `log_and_run mkdir 'Directory A' 'Directory B'` to `mkdir Directory A Directory B`, because the quotes are consumed at the first parsing stage and not still present at the `eval` stage.